# How does Java classpath assembly work ?

Tags: java, maven, ant, classpath

I've always taken the classpath for granted, i.e.  - its something that eclipse, maven , ant , etc handled for me.  Its obvious that the classpath is the place where java "looks" for binary classes which are executed / integrated with an application.

However, there are some intricacies which are not clearly described.

1) How does java "find" classes in the classpath ?

2) How are collisions handled by javac when looking into the classpath ?

3) What is happening "under the hood" when tools like maven/ant add/ignore elements to the classpath ?  Do these tools simply wrap the javac program ?

4) Finally : is there an example of a "manual" complicated build for java, that doesnt use the modern generation of build tools --- just for educational purposes -- which is available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Class location is just hierarchical by fully-qualified name. Getting the byte stream depends on the backing store, whether it's on the filesystem (just reads the file), in a jar (reads the zip entry), in a DB (gets the bytes). It's up to the classloader to translate the FQN to the byte stream.
2. Implementation-dependent. Generally first on the classpath wins, but that's not a requirement, it's just the easiest.
3. More or less.
4. You mean like an old `Makefile`-based one? Or a big ol' Ant one? Not sure what you're asking. It's mostly building up classpaths, which is easy, and creating artifacts.

Comment: Thanks ! could you elaborate on the "Creating artifacts" part ?

Comment: @jayunit100 Things like jars, wars, ears, javadocs, etc. None of it is overly-interesting (IMO), it's clerical.

Answer (score 0):

`man javac` and `man java` answer most of your questions.

3) They do simply wrap it